# Push into an Array inside an Object in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have the reducer that contains some of the list objects.

```
const list = [
  {
    name: 'A',
    products: { items: [] },
  },
  {
    name: 'B',
    products: { items: [{ qty: 1 }] },
  },
]
```

I want to add new items to the product key.
**reducer**

```
export const addProductToSubscription = (state, { name, products }) => ({
  ...state,
  list: state.list.map((v) =>
    name === v.subscriptionName ? [...v.products, { ...v.products, items: products }] : v
  ),
})
```

disptach like this,

```
dispatch("A",[{qty:2}])
```

**expected output**

```
const list = [
  {
    name: 'A',
    products: { items: [{ qty: 2 }] },
  },
  {
    name: 'B',
    products: { items: [{ qty: 1 }] },
  },
]
```

What reducer not updating the state.

Thanks!!

Comment: Does the `state` has a `list` key or the `list` is the `state`?

Comment: `arr.map` does not mutate the array, it returns a new array. That might change what you're trying to do in the second code block.

Comment: yes state has the list key

Comment: why this is not updating state

Answer (score 1):

I've recreated your environment and end up like-

```js
const state = {
    list: [
        {
            name: "A",
            products: { items: [] },
        },
        {
            name: "B",
            products: { items: [{ qty: 1 }] },
        },
    ],
};

const updateState = (state, { name, products }) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        list: state.list.map(v => {
          return {
            ...v,
            products: {
              ...v.products,
              items: [
                ...v.products.items,
                ...products
              ]
            }
          }
        }),
    };
};

const res = updateState(state, { name: "A", products: [{ qty: 2 }, {qty: 4}] });

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more advanced solution than `Object.assign` and spread operator(`...`) - [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper)

```js
const update = require('immutability-helper');
const assert = require('assert');

const list = [
  {
    name: 'A',
    products: { items: [] },
  },
  {
    name: 'B',
    products: { items: [{ qty: 1 }] },
  },
];

function addProductToSubscription(state = list, { name, products }) {
  return update(state, {
    $apply: (self) => {
      return self.map((v) => {
        if (v.name === name) {
          return update(v, { products: { items: { $push: products } } });
        }
        return v;
      });
    },
  });
}

const actual = addProductToSubscription(undefined, { name: 'A', products: [{ qty: 2 }] });

console.log(JSON.stringify(actual, null, 2));

assert(actual !== list, 'new copy');
assert(actual[0] !== list[0], 'new copy for A object');
assert(actual[0].products !== list[0].products, 'new copy for A object products');
assert(actual[0].products.items !== list[0].products.items, 'new copy for A object products items');
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "A",
    "products": {
      "items": [
        {
          "qty": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "products": {
      "items": [
        {
          "qty": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the new copy using spread operator and update to the state

```
export const addProductToSubscription = (state, { name, products }) => ({
  ...state,
  list: state.list.map((v) =>
    v.name === name
      ? {
          ...v,
          products: { items: [...v.products.items, ...products] },
        }
      : v
  ),
});
```